# AJAX using JQuery response error

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to setup an ajax call using JQuery. The URL I want to query is http://www.icis.com/rss/publicrss/

My jQuery looks like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.icis.com/rss/publicrss/",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "xml",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
  },
  success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

I get the following error:

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

If I paste the URL right into the browser I get the response so shouldn't be a CORS thing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the Access-control-allow-origin, this is for the server. Also, i suggest removing the content-type: text-plain, it will be a pain in the ass to works with plain text. I suggest using XML or Json

Comment: are you requesting as cross domain?

Comment: "_If I paste the URL right into the browser I get the response_" Your browser doesn't use JavaScript to request the page ;)

Comment: This will be used on a page on the same domain @RuhulAmin.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas good point. It also works in Postman. I only mention this to show how it can't be a cors thing (I don't think) as it doesn't have to be on the same domain to work. Just thought it would help to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'`

You can also try adding:

```
$.support.cors = true;
```